# Is the graph of the $\frac{1}{x^2}$ function a horizontal hyperbola?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, graphing-functions

Is the graph of the $\frac{1}{x^2}$ function a horizontal hyperbola? What type of function is this function? Is it a power function or a rational function?

Comment: Have you seen the plot ?

Answer (score 0):

A power function is in the form of
$$y=ax^n$$
In your case, $n = -2$, $a=1$.

A rational function is a fraction where both the numerator and the denominator are polynomials.

Since both $1$ and $x^2$ are polynomials, $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is a rational function.

Hyperbola is in the form of 
$$\frac{(x-h)^2}{a^2} - \frac{(y-k)^2}{b^2} = 1,$$
so $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is not a hyperbola.

In conclusion, $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is both a rational functional and a power function, but not a hyperbola.

Edit: $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is not a conic section, so it should not be considered as a hyperbola.

Comment: I don't find this answer satisfying since $1/x$ is a rational function and a power function, doesn't fit into the form you gave but is still a hyperbola.

Comment: That equation describes an ellipse, not a hyperbola. A hyperbola has a minus sign where you have a plus sign.

Comment: @TonyK: Thanks, I have made the correction.

Comment: More generally a conic section has an equation of the form $A x^2 + B xy + C y^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0$ - and this conic section is a hyperbola if and only if $B^2 - 4AC > 0$.  On the other hand, the closest you could get from $y = \frac{1}{x^2}$ is $x^2 y = 1$ which is a cubic curve.

Comment: @B. Mehta: You are right, I didn't consider that.

Comment: @Larry the problem is that "1/x^2" is being used as the graph, which is the solution set of the equation y=1/x^2, which is not so obviously not equivalent to an equation of your form, although in fact it's not.